# Oops! Terminal is opening all applications with texteditor after Open with:/Change All

Tags: terminal, finder

I messed up. I was opening a text file with no visible extension and macOS defaulted to opening it as an executable. I changed it to open with TextEdit then did the "Open with:"/"Change All..." via the info menu.

Now, I'm trying to open a program through terminal and it's opening that program through TextEdit. How do I change it back to opening all non-extension files as .exe files?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I should have waited two minutes before posting. I went back to the original file that didn't have an extension, right click, info, Open With..., then chose terminal (under utilities). That fixed it.